# execute string on jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

My starting point is

```
lock('pswAppAutomatedParallelTests0') {
    lock('pswAppAutomatedParallelTests1') {
        sh "sudo /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server"
        sh "sudo /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices"
        ....
    }
}
```

Which works ok!

But now, I'm building something that should lock an arbitrary nr of devices before running the commands.

My initial thoughts were to create a snippet (based on the inputed number of devices) and then run that.

So, the first question is: is that a decent approach?

Assuming so, I'm building a string and trying to execute it as part of the pipeline. My Jenkinsflie looks like this:

```
def lockDevicesThenRunCommands(devices, commands) {
        // lets make a sandwich
        def topBread = ""
        def bottomBread = " "

        devices.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
            topBread+="lock(lockTagForDevice${index}) {  "
            bottomBread+="}"
        }

        def sandwich = "${topBread}${commands}${bottomBread}"
        echo "${sandwich}"

        //return { "${sandwich}" }          <-- build the step
        //return { print("${sandwich}") }   <-- build the step
        //"${sandwich}".execute             <-- just call function
        //print("${sandwich}").execute()    <-- just call function
}

pipeline {
    
    (...)

    steps {
        // If any task is alreaddy running on any of the devices, do not kill the server
        script{
    
            def serials = ["Some", "List", "Of", "Devices"] // I get a list of the serials of the devices but that is not the point here...
            def commands = "echo I print stuff."
    
            [ "Some Name" : lockDevicesThenRunCommands("${serials}", "${commands}")]    // <--  build the step
            // lockDevicesThenRunCommands("${serials}", "${commands}")                  // <--  just call function
        }
    }

}
```

The `echo ${sandwich}` actually outputs:

```
lock(lockTagForDevice0) {  lock(lockTagForDevice1) {  lock(lockTagForDevice2) {  lock(lockTagForDevice3) {  echo I print stuff. }}}}
```

Which looks good to me... but I still can't seam to get that string to be executed as if it was part of the pipeline.

So the second question is: **Is there some** groovy or Jenkins pipeline **way to execute the string in my variable** (`sandwich`) as part of the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

we have something similar where we have bunch of functions (commands) in a shared library then in a pipeline we choose which command to run by name inside a `GString`

Trick is to put them in a Map

```
def aCommand = {..do something}
def bCommand = {..do something}

def commandMap = ['aCommand': aCommand, 'bCommand': bCommand]
```

then you build a string var with the name of the command to execute

```
def commandToExec = 'aCommand'
```

Now to execute you would just do just this:

```
println "${commandMap[commandToExec]()}"
```